# Flash Messages TYPO3 6 to 7 update

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I used the following syntax in an TYPO3 6 exbase extension before migrating to 7:

```
$this->flashMessageContainer->flush();
$this->flashMessageContainer->getAllMessagesAndFlush();
$this->flashMessageContainer->add(Tx_Extbase_Utility_Localization::translate('undefined error', $this->extensionName));
```

In my new code I would use:

```
$this->addFlashMessage(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility::translate('undefined error', $this->extensionName));
```

But I always get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getFlashMessageQueue() on a
>   non-object in /srv/www/typo3_src-7.6.32/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php on line 190

Any ideas about this behaviour?

Thanks and best regards,

Chris

Comment: I assume you add the flash message in a controller context, right? What class does the controller extend?

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: TYPO3 v7.6 reached end-of-life and is not maintained anymore)

In order to understand what's going on, let's have a look into the source code (referring to the error message you posted, checking `AbstractController.php`)

```
$this->controllerContext->getFlashMessageQueue()->enqueue($flashMessage);
```

https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_7-6/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php#L190

```
$this->controllerContext = $this->buildControllerContext();
```

https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_7-6/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php#L238

Thus, my assumption(!) is, that you override `public function processRequest(...)` in your application specific controller without invoking `parent::processRequest(...)` leading to the situation that `$this->controllerContext` is not initialized.